# Oracle Procedure alter pivoted data to unpivot and push into different destination

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I have a PL/SQL procedure which takes string at runtime which is comma separated,splits it and pushes into table.
Example of procedure and table is given here:
Procedure is push_data.
Current table where data is getting inserted is push_data_temp.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fae31c11a4ad6205ebcaa418a0bffffd

Now as per requirement, i need to write a new procedure where logic would remain same of splitting data, but in the new table push_data_pivot(structure inside pivot), should display data pivoted in this format.

Ex: if currently data in push_data_temp is:
[image]

The data should go in push_data_pivot in the new procedure as:
[image]

The logic should remain same, just that the data getting inserted would go into columns instead of rows, populating id and value columns.

Here column **id**, is the unique identifier for the string passed in both tables. Basically, it is same as the one used in original table.

PUSH_DATA_PIVOT :

```
 create table PUSH_DATA_PIVOT
(
id_pk NUMBER,
  id NUMBER,
  label_id number,
  label varchar2(4000),
  value varchar2(4000)
);

insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL01',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL02',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL03',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL04',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL05',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL06',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL07',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL08',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL09',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL10',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL11',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL12',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL13',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL14',null);
```

The sample data is single string, for single label_id and corresponding set of column label values.However actual table would have multiple such strings inserted on basis of id column, same as original requirement.

**The only requirement is, to create new procedure with new destination table as push_data_pivot and data in unpivoted format. Split logic would be same as in existing procedure.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this question.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=412a6e27a22741ee1c31eee4a3f2bf3a

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not simply unpivot the hole table

> ```
> SELECT * FROM push_data_temp;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PK |  ID | COL1                         | COL2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | COL3     | COL4       | COL5                | COL6                                 | COL7           | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12    | COL13 | COL14
> ----: | --: | :--------------------------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------- | :--------- | :------------------ | :----------------------------------- | :------------- | :--- | :--- | :---- | :---- | :------- | :---- | :----
>  null | 110 | Project title afor BYU heads | "The values are,<br> "exactly" up to the requirement and analysis done by the team.<br>Also it is difficult to,<br> prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team" | "Active" | "Disabled" | "25 tonnes of fuel" | "www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;" | "Apprehension" | null | null | null  | "25"  | "Stable" | null  | null 
>  null | 111 | Project title for IT Heads   | "The values are,<br> "exactly" up to the requirement and analysis done by the team.<br>Also it is difficult to,<br> prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team" | "Active" | "Disabled" | "25 tonnes of fuel" | "www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;" | "Apprehension" | null | null | null  | "25"  | "Stable" | null  | null
> ```

> ```
> create table PUSH_DATA_PIVOT
> (
> id_pk NUMBER,
>   id NUMBER,
>   label_id number,
>   label varchar2(4000),
>   value varchar2(4000)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PUSH_DATA_PIVOT
> SELECT 1,ID,1,label,value
> FROM
> (SELECT * FROM push_data_temp
> UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS(
>     value
>     FOR label 
>     IN (
>         col1 AS 'COL01', 
>         col2 AS 'COL02', 
>         col3 AS 'COL03', 
>         col4 AS 'col4', 
>         col5 AS 'col5', 
>         col6 AS 'COL06', 
>         col7 AS 'COL07', 
>         col8 AS 'COL08', 
>         col9 AS 'COL09', 
>         col10 AS 'COL10', 
>         col11 AS 'COL11', 
>         col12 AS 'COL12', 
>         col13 AS 'COL13', 
>         col14 AS 'COL14'
>     )
> )) t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> 28 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from push_data_pivot;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_PK |  ID | LABEL_ID | LABEL | VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
> ----: | --: | -------: | :---- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL01 | Project title afor BYU heads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL02 | "The values are,<br> "exactly" up to the requirement and analysis done by the team.<br>Also it is difficult to,<br> prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team"
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL03 | "Active"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>     1 | 110 |        1 | col4  | "Disabled"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
>     1 | 110 |        1 | col5  | "25 tonnes of fuel"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL06 | "www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL07 | "Apprehension"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL08 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL09 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL10 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL11 | "25"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL12 | "Stable"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL13 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 110 |        1 | COL14 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL01 | Project title for IT Heads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL02 | "The values are,<br> "exactly" up to the requirement and analysis done by the team.<br>Also it is difficult to,<br> prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team"
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL03 | "Active"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>     1 | 111 |        1 | col4  | "Disabled"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
>     1 | 111 |        1 | col5  | "25 tonnes of fuel"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL06 | "www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL07 | "Apprehension"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL08 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL09 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL10 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL11 | "25"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL12 | "Stable"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL13 | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>     1 | 111 |        1 | COL14 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=306600c27ffa4a7bc495fb85ee3d86cf)*

Comment: I cannot use push_data_temp table now. I gave that for reference. i now need to insert in push_data_pivot using proc.